# how to display a progress bar until my page loads?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I use php to fetch some information from database and I want to display a progress bar until my php executes and I need to display my page after the php execution. how can I achieve this.

Excatly like how the gmail loads the inbox

Comment: A progress bar presumes that your page loads in multiple steps.  Draw a progress bar in the page using Javascript (or any one of a number of readily available methods that you can find using Google), and advance the bar for each step.

Comment: Your questions is too vague. What have you tried?

Comment: To add to what @RobertHarvey noted. What you are looking for can really only be executed using AJAX to load page components after initial page load.  So the basic workflow is browser makes request.  Server/PHP application reply with initial HTML that shows progress bar.  You then asynchronously load page components using AJAX, updating progress bar while doing so.

Comment: Check the page for loaded components... advancing a progress meter as each one is filled in. Once all components are there hide the overlay

Comment: @ladieu how to check for the loaded components?

Comment: If you don't use a progress bar, then your page will load faster - negating the need for a progress bar.

Comment: Giri,

You can have the loaded HTML populate a javascript variable. The contents of these variables can be checked.

var bla = 0; //the bla component is not loaded

have the content set bla =1 when loaded.  This is the simplest way

Comment: Giri.. use http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp  SetTimeout... check for loaded components and display your progress. If more things need to load just set a new timeout.  I would set the timeout for 500ms

If everything is loaded then close your overlay instead of setting a new timeout.

Comment: atleast make research and put your effort.Then ask somebody.Tell us what you have tried friend ?

Answer (score 3):

Have look at https://github.com/TheBrockEllis/jQuery-and-PHP-Progress-Bar
and also http://www.johnboy.com/blog/a-better-php-upload-progress-bar-using-jquery

It is fairly simple to do.

Answer (score 2):

From the description I don't know how in depth this progress bar needs to be. This is pseudo code that should get you started. It won't run AS IS... you will need to make these functions do something.

EXAMPLE 1: 100% client side checker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* in document head */
var section1 = 0;
var section2 = 0;
var section3 = 0;
var section4 = 0;

//lightbox w/ progress meter
showProgressLightBox();

//async ajax calls here to load the various sectoins
loadPage(); // not a real function



function displayProgressMeter()
{
   var count = 0;
   if (section1) count++;
   if (section2) count++;
   if (section3) count++;
   if (section4) count++;

   if (count != 4) {
     displayProgress(count); //will repaint lightbox progress meter
       //based on X of Y sections loaded
       setTimeout('displayProgressMeter()',500);
   }
   else
   {
        closeLightBox(); //page is loaded
   }

}

displayProgressMeter(); //start the event

//note my ajax calls will flip the values of the various variables we are checking


</script>
```

Example 2 server checker. I have something like this running for a project that takes about 30 minutes to run a certain activity. The progress itself is updated by updating mysql from a cron scheduled task

First I have a PHP file called "batchStatusChecker" which looks something like this:

```
<?php
define('AREA',"COLREPORT");
include(__DIR__."/../phoenix/includes/config.php");
session_start();


$batch=(int)@$_REQUEST["batch"];
include (__DIR__."/affiliateUploadClass.php");

$rs=Query("select commitMessage from phx_AffiliateUsersFiles where ID=$batch;");

echo json_encode(array("info" => $rs->Get("commitMessage")));



?>
```

Then I have some javascript that updates a div with the current status or shows a completion message. You could adapt a technique like this to your needs if it is more appropriate for your use case

```
    function checkStatusOfReport()
    {

        $.post("/affiliateUpload/batchStatusChecker.php", { "batch": <? echo $batch; ?> },
        function(data)
        {
            if (data.error)
            {
                $("#ErrorInformation").html(data.error);
                $("#UploadInformation").remove();
            }
            else
            {
                var msg="<h3>" + data.info + "</h3>";

                $("#UploadInformation").html(msg);

                if (data.info == 'COMPLETE')
                    $("#UploadInformation").html('<h3>The import of this batch is completed.</h3>');
                else
                    setTimeout("checkStatusOfReport()",4000);


            }
        }, "json");

    }

    checkStatusOfReport();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Progress bar holder -->
<div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
<!-- Progress information -->
<div id="information" style="width"></div>
<?php
// Total processes
$total = 2;

// Loop through process
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
    // Calculate the percentation
    $percent = intval($i/$total * 100)."%";

    // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
    echo '<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
    </script>';


// This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);


// Send output to browser immediately
    flush();


// Sleep one second so we can see the delay
    sleep(1);
}

// Tell user that the process is completed
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```